# Which is the problem, the for loop or the if statement? (Helsinki MOOC project)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

If the user searches a number within the array, the system should spit out the index that the number is located. If the number is not in the array, then the system should print out "X was not found." Why will these two IF statements not do the trick?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array = new int[10];
    array[0] = 6;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 8;
    array[3] = 1;
    array[4] = 3;
    array[5] = 0;
    array[6] = 9;
    array[7] = 7;

    System.out.print("Search for?");
    int searching = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (searching == array[i]) {
            System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i);

        } if (searching!= array[1]) {
            System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
            break;
        }

    }
     // Implement the search functionality here
}
```

}

Comment: The second `if` statement compares with `array[1]` instead of `array[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length as well in the second if condition.
Also you have to break when the number is found.

please see below code for reference.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0] = 6;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 8;
        array[3] = 1;
        array[4] = 3;
        array[5] = 0;
        array[6] = 9;
        array[7] = 7;

        System.out.print("Search for?");
        int searching = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            if (searching == array[i]) {
                System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i);
                break;
            }
            if (searching != array[i] && i == (array.length - 1)) {
                System.out.println(searching + " was not found.");
                break;
            }

        }
        // Implement the search functionality here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement seems to always be checking index 1 of your array.

```
if (searching!= array[1]) {
        System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
        break;
    }
```

Additionally, checking for a value not being in the array should likely not occur within the for loop, but instead be assumed or tracked with a boolean if you reach the end of the for loop without finding a match.

Comment: Thanks, Eric.  I fixed that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (searching!= array[1]) {
    System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
    break;
}
```

This line doesn't makes sense because in the first iteration, it will check the first element of the array and if it doesn't match, it'll get out of the loop.

You can keep a track if the item was found by simply creating a boolean variable:

```
boolean found = false;
```

Then in your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (searching == array[i]) {
        System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i);
        found = true; 
        break;
        //When the search is done and we find the element, we make the found true
        //to indicate the search is finished. And we get out from the loop by "break"
    } 
}

// If the above loop didn't get into the if statement, this will never be true, 
// indicating that the number was not found in the array.

if(!found) 
    System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
```

Comment: Search for?7
7 was not found.
7 was not found.
7 was not found.
7 was not found.
7 was not found.
7 was not found.
7 was not found.
7 is at index 7

This is what that printed out. I see what's happening but I only want it to print out one line. Either that the number is found, or if it is not. For some reason, it's printing once for every failed attempt. And, It printed the statements backwards???

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check if the `searching` value is part of the array and only want to print one final answer.
I modified your code a little bit to explain my answer:

- removed `break;`
- changed `searching!= array[1]` to `searching!= array[i]`

  `for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (searching == array[i]) {
         System.out.println(searching + " is at index " + i);
      }
      if (searching!= array[i]) {
         System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
      }
  }`

In this solution we print the result for every element of the array. You choosed an array with 10 elements. You set the values for the first 8 elments. The rest will be default initiliased with `0`.

Assuming `searching` is `0`. Iterating through the for-loop will result in the following prints:

- First element 6 -> "0 was not found."
- Second element 2 -> "0 was not found."
- ...
- Sixth element 0 -> "0 is at index 5"
- Seventh element 7 -> "0 was not found."
- Eighth element 2 -> "0 was not found."
- Ninth element 0 -> "0 is at index 8"
- Tenth element -> "0 is at index 9"

If you want one answer you can modify the term like this

```
//Searching for the element
Integer index = null;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (searching == array[i]) {
       index = i;
       break;  //quits the for-loop when the value searching is found
    }
}

// Printing the result
if (index != null) {
   System.out.println("First occurance of "+ searching + " at index " + i);
} else {
   System.out.println(searching +" was not found.");
}
```

I wish you much fun while programming.

Comment: Upvoted this. Thank you.learning programming has very high highs and very low lows right now. haha

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the debugger to get better understanding of the loop and conditions.

For example, what is the purpose of `searching!= array[1]` statement?

Is "else" missing in the following line `} if (searching!= array[1]) {`? And so forth...

You need to be more specific with the question in terms of: what behavior do you expect and what is the actual behavior of the code fragment. 
Then you will get more help and explanations here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Obviously I'm new here and I'll try and take better care, but this is my 4th week learning this, It's a bit tricky. 

So the "1" is supposed to be an "i".

 I thought " if (searching != array[i]) { meant, If the int searching does NOT equal the array[i]...then...